# Express js route 404 error only in prod

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I've been working on building a video conferencing application by following [this tutorial](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2018/03/video-chat-react.html).

It's a great tutorial, and everything worked awesome when developing.  However, when pushing to production I had issues and I'm not well-versed enough with these tools to figure out what's wrong.

I changed my `NODE_ENV=PROD` in my `.env` file. Which should trigger the production express build located [here](https://github.com/kimobrian/TwilioReact/blob/server-setup/server.js#L21).  (tutorial github link)

Next, I ran `npm run build` as I wanted to build my `bundle.js`, etc in the `dist/` directory.  I copied the three files from `dist/`,

```
bundle.js
common.js
index.html
```

Into my web server's directory, but now when visiting `/token` route, I get a 404.  This doesn't happen on DEV, so it has to be something with the way the express `server.js` is written.

Unfortunately, I'm having trouble deducing what the issue is.

Environment details - I'm using a hostgator account, and copying files into the cpanel file manager.  I've hosted lot's of JS applications like this before, but usually if I'm using a back-end it's a django server, so this (express) is new for me.

Comment: Is your express server running in production ?

Comment: @FarhanTahir - my .env is set to production.  When I build, it transpiles into `common.js`.  Is there more I should be doing?  As I said, I'm not experienced with express.

Comment: You need to setup express server running on the production environment as well.  You see express is used to build the web server listening on specific port. 

Use npm `forever` or `pm2` for these not sure what kind of hosting you are using though.

Comment: I'm using hostgator.  I thought you could use express to host static files as so:  https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Comment: Here's the express `server.js`:  https://github.com/kimobrian/TwilioReact/blob/server-setup/server.js

Comment: Yes but to server these files you need to run the express server in production. 

Also I saw in server.js file the following line is checking for static files in `dist` directory where I guess you copied those files and pasted in the root of web server correct ? 

` app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "dist")));`

Comment: So I guess no `dist` exists there ? correct me if I'm wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169136/discussion-between-atschaal-and-farhan-tahir).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because `express` server is not running in your production environment. As express is used to build web server listening on specific port. In your case you have deployed the `static` files but the server is not running.